# Cannot Find Bonjour Connected Computers

Tags: macos, bonjour

I have three Mac Notebooks on a local network all connected to the same router. Two of the notebooks use Airport (not the base station), and the third one is wired to the ethernet.

Airport notebooks can see each other and the ethernet connected notebook, however ethernet connected notebook cannot see airport connected notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

Which make and model of router?

Sounds like the router is using a separate subnet for the wireless, instead of having the wireless connections "bridge" into the main pool. From the wired's perspective, the wireless computers are hidden behind the subnet's NAT, and not visible.

Look for configuration options for how the wireless is setup.

Comment: to confirm this what are the IP addresses of the machines